# How to store list of file name into a single list and send it through email?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got an application that scan certain directories for any file which exceeds certain size. After it detects it, it will send a warning email, stating that certain files have reached certain size limits. My problem is my current program will send one email per file. Meaning if there is 10 file that is over limit, then it will will send 10 email. How to make it compile all of the file and send a list of those file in a single email?Here is my code if needed:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = 0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();


        List<string> s1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\gdimaging\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\hios\DATA", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\imgviewer\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newcnas\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newpod\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\OMS\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\WEBIMG", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());


        dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
        dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
        dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
        ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();      
        foreach(string s in s1)
        {   
            try
            {   
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(s);
                FileSystemInfo sysInfo = new FileInfo(s);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                //System.Collections.Generic.List<string> nameList;
                dr["File_Name"] = sysInfo.Name;
                dr["File_Type"] = sysInfo.Extension;
                dr["File_Size"] = (info.Length / 1024).ToString();
                dr["Create_Date"] = sysInfo.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {
                    fileList.Add(sysInfo.Name);
                }

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
                continue;
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show(fileList + "overlimit!!");
```

}

Comment: The email and password you wrote down up there might be actual?

Comment: em??actual??no thats just dummy email I set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the Mail options in a class
with a public method/attribute that returns a boolean if one of the files meets the criteria and only perform the mail operations if the criteria are met:

something like this -- not checked as it was done on a mac in a text editor

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count = 0;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer.Start();


    List<string> s1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\gdimaging\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\hios\DATA", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\imgviewer\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newcnas\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newpod\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\OMS\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
    s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\WEBIMG", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());

    //s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\gdimaging\data", "*.*");
    dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
    dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
    dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
    // new mail list class
    class mailList {
    public bool isEmpty = true;
    MailMessage mailMessage;
    // do all the onceonly stuff in the constructor
        public mailList(){
            mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("shahrul1509@yahoo.com"));
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("shahrul_kakashi90@hotmail.com"));
    // set subject
            mailMessage.Subject = "FILE SIZE WARNING MESSAGE";
            // Identify the credentials to login to the gmail account  
            string sendEmailsFrom = "shahrul1509@gmail.com";
                    // password below is written in * to encrypt it

            string sendEmailsFromPassword = "***4556**";
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(sendEmailsFrom, sendEmailsFromPassword);
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
            mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailClient.Timeout = 20000;
            mailClient.Credentials = cred;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("shahrul1509@gmail.com", "Shahrul Nizam");

        }
        public addFile(String fileName){
            mailMessage.Body = mailMessage.Body + sysInfo.Name+ "HAS REACH ITS SIZE LIMIT.";
            isEmpty = false;
        }
        public send(){
            mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
            MessageBox.Show("Email Notification Sent!");
        }
    }

    }
    try
        {
        mailList ml = new mailList();
        foreach(string s in s1)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(s);
                FileSystemInfo sysInfo = new FileInfo(s);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
            //System.Collections.Generic.List<string> nameList;
                dr["File_Name"] = sysInfo.Name;
                dr["File_Type"] = sysInfo.Extension;
                dr["File_Size"] = (info.Length / 1024).ToString();
                dr["Create_Date"] = sysInfo.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {
                    ml.addFile(sysInfo.Name);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }

                }
                if(ml.isEmpty==false){
                    ml.Send();
                }
            }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paddy for the suggestions. But may I've edited my code. I tried to use ArrayList and I use a MessageBox instead of sending email just to test whether it works or not. Now when I use ArrayList, when I run the program, it pop up a message : System.Collection.Arraylist is overlimit. 
It suppose to pop up the file name but it didn't. Can point out to me what's wrong?

Comment: You have busted the limit on array list, maybe you have a problem with your loop and it's returning far too many rows, perhaps check the capacity and IsFixedSize properties of your ArrayList and then the count property while it executes

Comment: ArrayList got limit?Because I just use the list to store those files which exceeds the size limit which currently around 10+ files.

Answer (score 1):

After you check the file sizes in a foreach loop then add these files which exceed the certain limit to another array and join the array element in your message body which is located out of the for-loop.

Comment: Just to ask an opinion, is it advisable for me to move the email sending part of my code outside the loop, then within the file size checking using if, I append all of the file which exceeds the size into a List, then I just use the List to send the email??(sorry I'm still new to programming)